# Enforcing correct ordering of volatile memory location accesses

Tags: c, embedded

Consider the following snippet:

```
volatile uint32_t *registers;
\\ ...
\\ registers gets mmap'd and so on
\\ ...
registers[0] = 0x1;
registers[1] = 0x1;
```

In this `registers` is initialised from an `mmap` to some peripheral address space (hence the volatile).

I've yet to see this discussed anywhere, but in my mind in the general case, these register writes (or indeed any register accesses) should be protected from each other by a memory barrier. The problem being if the peripheral is expecting the accesses to be correctly ordered, the compiler may well ignore that.

So it should look something like:

```
volatile uint32_t *registers;
pthread_mutex_t reg_mutex;

\\ ...
\\ registers gets mmap'd and so on
\\ ...
pthread_mutex_lock(&reg_mutex);
registers[0] = 0x1;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&reg_mutex);

pthread_mutex_lock(&reg_mutex)
registers[1] = 0x1;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&reg_mutex);
```

Is my reasoning correct? Have I missed something? Is there a better way to do this?

It seems to me that this should be core to any understanding of using memory mapped devices.

EDIT: In response to the questions, I've noted that there is potential issues with the out-of-order execution of instructions. In which case, I'll rephrase the question to address that explicitly: Is a memory barrier the correct approach to constrain the processor to order correctly? (and is a mutex a valid strategy for this?)

Comment: Memory barriers are not part of the guarantees for `volatile`. If you need them, you have to use `stdatomic.h` facilities. Or you set up the hardware appropriately, which is the typical way.

Comment: @Olaf so my reasoning is sound?

Comment: As I wrote: it depends on the hardware and its setup. A simple `mmap` will not suffice without additional guarantees. The standard does not cover implementation details for obvious reasons.

Comment: You just broadended your question even more. Wrt mutex: What would be the other thread using the mutex?

Comment: @Olaf a mutex enforces a memory fence.

Comment: No, it does not. It enforces a thread fence. That _might_ include a memory barrier, but not necessarily, e.g. if the platform is fully cache-coherent. And still: **what would be the other thread(s) of the mutex**? You would do better with atomics.

Comment: @Olaf thank you. That's a really helpful contribution.

Comment: This makes for interesting (and I think relevant) reading: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/memory-barriers.txt

Comment: The question is a bit void if you don't tell us what concurrent or conflicting memory accesses could occur - If there aren't and there is no one else trying to access the register, why would you want to protect them?

Comment: @tofro So the hypothetical is that some device depends on read and or writes to specific address in the correct sequence. Let's say a write triggers an action and a second write to a different address stops the action. These have to occur in the correct order.

Comment: Just to add to this wrt a mutex. The [ARM docs](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka14041.html) tell me that on ARMs at least, a mutex will impose a memory fence. I suspect this was where my slightly erroneous understanding came from.

Comment: If you're using an ARM, it would make more sense to simply use a [barrier](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka14041.html).

Comment: @Groo yup, that's where I've got to. Actually gcc's `__sync_synchronise()`.

Comment: @HenryGomersall: As Olaf pointed out, it depends on your architecture whether `__sync_synchronize` will actually emit any CPU instructions, so make sure you check this after compilation.

Answer (score 1):

According to the C and C++ standards, accesses to volatile memory locations are never reordered, so you don't have to do anything special. They are also never combined, so if you do sth like this:

```
registers[0] = 0x1;
registers[0] = 0x1;
registers[0] = 0x1;
registers[0] = 0x1;
```

The compiler will generate 4 memory writes.

See the latest draft of C11 standard - http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf

> 6.7.3 Type qualifiers
>
> ...
>
> 7 An object that has volatile-qualified type may be modified in ways unknown to the
>   implementation or have other unknown side effects. Therefore any expression referring
>   to such an object shall be evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine,
>   as described in 5.1.2.3. **Furthermore, at every sequence point the value last stored in the
>   object shall agree with that prescribed by the abstract machine**, except as modified by the
>   unknown factors mentioned previously.134) What constitutes an access to an object that
>   has volatile-qualified type is implementation-defined.

In your example each line is actually a "full expression" (as each one is terminated with a `;`) so each line contains a sequence point. Above requirement forces all the accesses to be performed in given order with no optimizations, reordering or any clever tricks.

However - do note, that this only states that compiler will generate instructions that access these memory locations in the exact order and number as in the source code. If you for example need to synchronize these accesses between multiple cores, then this is all hardware-dependent and any C standard won't help you here. Anyway - a mutex may be a bit too much to force such synchronization. You'd be better off by using some intrinsic functions of the compiler for that.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that? My understanding was accesses to the same volatile memory location are not reordered. In my example, it is to different locations.

Comment: @HenryGomersall: I agree a reference to the C standard (the question is about that language) would be nice. But the accesses are indeed not reordered **by the compiler**. That does not guarantee your hardware will not!

Comment: Expressions don't contain semicolons. And statements are not the only sequence points. And there still is a reference missing to support that accesses to **different** `volatile` qualified objects are not reordered (you will find them at the abstract machine specification;-)

Comment: @Olaf ach, I went through all this ages ago and noted that the machine out-of-order execution that might be the problem here (this question was an exercise me trying to remember my learnings). Memory barriers protect against this right?

Comment: @HenryGomersall: Please read the details of your platform. Your questions are way too broad for this site; there are just too many platforms and configurations even for the same platform.

Comment: @Olaf I really don't know what are you talking about... "Expressions don't contain semicolons." - sure, they don't, but a semicolon is a "thing" that terminates majority of "full expressions", which then become sequence points. For example "4) There is a sequence point after the evaluation of a full expression (an expression that is not a subexpression: **typically something that ends with a semicolon** or a controlling statement of if/switch/while/do) and before the next full expression." http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order (same info in the standard)

Comment: @Olaf What? Please don't be so dismissive. This isn't the first time I've been on SO and I've been writing C for 15 years so I'm no noob. Do you really have nothing constructive beyond RTFM? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier) tells me memory barriers are a suitable way to solve the out-of-order execution issue, so that's not unreasonable. I can use some gcc primitives to impose a memory fence, but the benefit of a mutex is I can gain thread safety too.

Comment: @FreddieChopin: A semicolon turns an expression into a statement. You really should learn the terminology when answering questions about the standard. And it's a punctuator, not a "thing". Statements or expressions don't "become sequence points". Worse: An expression can have multiple sequence points already (e.g. function call, logical operators). _Full expressions_ are not necessarily terminated by a semicolon either. And there are no controlling statements. You mean _controlling expressions_?

Comment: @FreddieChopin I'm still to be convinced that volatile protects different registers for which accesses may be order sensitive. Indeed, one could construct an example with two different volatiles for the which spec wouldn't say much at all, but the ordering could still be crucial.

Comment: @HenryGomersall: So, if Wikipedia tells you why ask me at all? I have over 30 years of programming experience at very different abstraction layers. And you shoudl study your platform first. There are different types of memory barriers, different types of memory areas/page attributes, depending on the hardware and configuration. I tried to point out that there is no single recipe. But feel free to notice that yourself, I'm out.

Comment: @HenryGomersall - in my understanding of the standard (which matches what GCC is doing), any access to volatile object will be made without reordering. Any reordering or optimizations would violate the emphasised part of the quote - no matter if you use one volatile pointer or ten.

Comment: @Olaf Clearly you think SO is a reasonable place to interact with fellow programmers. Comments like "feel free to notice that yourself" are hardly conducive to a reasonable discussion. Of course I'm aware there are hardware specific issues, but I'm still not clear why this question is hardware specific. With C there are ways of imposing memory fences (some of which may be through hardware specific asm, but others like a mutex are not - at least not to the library user), which it seems to me are potentially needed in conjunction with volatiles. None of that is hardware specific.

Comment: I think this answer is correct for the question (tagged _C_ and _embedded_). mmap(), semaphores, threads and so on are another matter.

Comment: You wonder why **hardware specific memory mapped IO** is hardware-specific? Why `volatile` is implementation-defined (did you even read the citation in this answer? FYI: "What constitutes an access to an object that has volatile-qualified type is **implementation-defined**." (emphasis mine))?